# Sum function to evaluate a summation in r for multiple n's

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

Lets say I want to calculate the sum of 2^i for i=0:n
And n=5,10,15. So I want to get 3 different answers. I don't want to sub n equal to each one individually . I was able to do it using a for loop while looping through each n. But I was wondering if there is a way to just put n without looping.

I tried doing

n=c(5,10,15)
sum(2^(0:n))
But that obviously didnt work, is there a way in r in which I can do this?

Comment: Try `vapply(n,function(x) sum(2^(0:x)),1)`. @G5W your line is the same as `2^n`.

Comment: Keep in mind also that, in this case, `sum(2^(0:n))` is equal to `2^(n-1)-1`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working:

```
n <- c(5,10,15)
sapply(n, function(x) sum(2^(0:x)))
#[1]    63  2047 65535
```

`sapply` is a function that performs `function(x)` on each element of the vector given, in this case - `n`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful